# Trying to add Keyboard navigation option to OwlCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

by default, OwlCarousel slides can't be moved using the keyboard. I used this code to add the feature but returns an error.

```
var owl = $('#carousel-div-id').data('owlCarousel');
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function(event) {
// handle cursor keys
if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    owl.prev();
} else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    owl.next();
}
});
```

The error is as follows

> Uncaught ReferenceError: owl is not defined

Comment: Is this carousel-div-id the correct owl id? Can you provide a demo?

Comment: @IrvinDominin That is just to give you an idea that it is the ID of the div on which we call the .owlCarousel() function.  The original id is "owl-example" as in the demo files on their website.

Please check this demo [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrrnair/8bJUc/225/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. Those who want to add keyboard functionality to OwlCarousel can use the following method.

```
//Usual Owlcarousel code.
$(document).ready(function() {
   var owl = $("#owl-example");
   owl.owlCarousel({
       pagination: true
   });

//Following code would do the trick.
 $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 37) {
       owl.trigger('owl.prev');
   } 
   else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        owl.trigger('owl.next');
   }

 });
});
```

**UPDATE**

`owl.trigger('owl.prev'), owl.trigger('owl.next')` would not work with Owl Carousel 2. Instead, Please use

```
 owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
```

and

```
owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
```